# unable to load Grid-Gain cache configuration file

Tags: gridgain

I am trying to start `grid-gain` by `bin\ignite.bat examples\config\example-cache.xml`

Also I have set `JAV_HOME` and `GRIDGAIN_HOME PATH`

To start `gridgain` I am using below code

```
Grid g = GridGain.start("/C:/Grid-Gain/ignite-fabric-1.0.0-RC1/ignite-fabric-1.0.0-RC1/examples/config/example-cache.xml");
```

I also tried with partial path

```
Grid g = GridGain.start("examples/config/example-cache.xml");
```

but all the time it is throwing exception

> Exception in thread "main" class org.gridgain.grid.GridException: Failed to find grid configuration in: file:/C:/Grid-Gain/ignite-fabric-1.0.0-RC1/ignite-fabric-1.0.0-RC1/examples/config/example-cache.xml

All the time it shows this error.

Comment: The error is pretty explicit.  It can't find the configuration information it needs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using GridGain and Ignite interchangeably, while you probably want to use Apache Ignite only. GridGain is an enterprise product sitting on top of the Apache Ignite.

Please take a look at [Apache Ignite Getting Started](http://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started) guide and the rest of the documentation. There is also a [community forum](http://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.0/discuss) there where you can ask questions.